# Empathy 3.6, telepathy haze, libpurple and skype -> Please help me to mix them well

Tags: gnome, empathy

I'm trying to connect skype to empathy, and here is what I have done so far.

I got Pidgin to display my skype contacts so Skype <-> libpurple works, but Empathy 3.6 does not show my Skype contacts.

I have both `pidgin-skype` and `telepathy-haze` installed.

I suppose the problem is that Empathy 3.6 gets its accounts from Ubuntu Online Accounts, but I cannot add Skype there. Is there any UOA plugin that adds skype support. It does not have to be based on `libpurple` and `telepathy-haze` (In fact better if it is not)

Please help. Thanks.